# Can I make global function in jQuery without having to make any changes to variables?

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have this code in a php-file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/party.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    loadParty('<?php echo $party_id;?>');    
});
</script>
```

in the `party.js` - file a function called `loadParty()` exists.

With above code, `loadParty()` is called - but nothing happens because `loadParty()` isn't initalized.

The external party.js file...

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    //code...

    function loadParty(id) {
         //code for loading party
    }
}
```

In firebug I get **ReferenceError**: `loadOutfit` is not defined.

Can I define the loadParty() as global?

I've tried this...

```
$.loadParty = loadParty(party_id) {
    //code...

    //party_id is set as unused (by my IDE), and the function do 
    //not work work at all. My guess is that the variables inside a global function
    //must be global as well??? 
}
```

Is there any way of defining a javascript function globally (`loadParty()`) accessible without having the variables inside it to be that?). The only thing I want to do is to call the js-function like this: `loadParty(4);` (from a php-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOM ready($(document).ready(function(){)` handler is a anonymous  function so your `loadParty()` function has `local scope`.

So you can  not call it outside the `DOM ready`

---

Try

You can remove DOM ready and place your script file at the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks a lot! :-) I moved my actual function outside of DOM ready because it doesn't matter if the function itself were initialized before it was USED :-) It's USED first after DOM ready... Thanks for getting me on right track! :-)